# How do I import objects from Typescript to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For some reason I'm working on a JavaScript project, but I need to import objects from another npm local module("file:/path/to/file") written by TypeScript. 
The TypeScript file export an Object:

```
export * from './Model'
```

After compiling this typescript project into `bundle.js` via webpack.
I tried to import bundle.js into the JavaScript project, got an Object with nothing in it(`{}`) was got.

```
import * as model from 'path/to/bundle.js'
console.log(model)
// {} was got
```

Is there any way to import some objects from TypeScript to JavaScript?

Comment: Can we have a look at `bundle.js`? Have you tried to import to TypeScript to check if the export is correct, before importing to JavaScript?

Comment: I'm sure what exports is correct, I can import it from another typescript,  even I can get it from `console.XX` in JS if I set it like this :`import * as model from './Model';Object.assign(console, {XX:model});` in TS @RaphaMex

Comment: OK. So I can just recommend you transpile your bundle to compatible JavaScript with *babel* or equivalent.